# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

[image]I am getting

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

on but don't really know how to track down the root cause of this. My code makes use of INTULocationRequestBlock and so on.

**UPDATE:** The cause of the crash is due to the fact that the webserviceCall (see code below) never calls onCompletion and when the code is run again, I got the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. I verified this is indeed the case, but not sure why or how to prevent this.

```
locationManager.requestLocation(withDesiredAccuracy: INTULocationAccuracy.city, timeout: 30.0, block: { (_ currentLocation: CLLocation, _ achievedAccuracy: INTULocationAccuracy, _ status: INTULocationStatus) in
     if status == INTULocationStatus.success {
            self._searchNearbyProperties(withCoordinate: currentLocation.coordinate)
     } else {
         self.delegate?.propertyManager(self, didFailToFindProperties: "Unable to find your current location.")
     }

} as! INTULocationRequestBlock)
```

Comment: Why are you forcefully typecasting/unwrapping the block to INTULocationRequestBlock? What is the signature for INTULocationRequestBlock? Do you need to typecast here?

Comment: i am forcefully typecasting/unwrapping to INTULocationRequestBlock,swift compiler force me to typecast.                                 INTULocationRequestBlock = (CLLocation?, INTULocationAccuracy, INTULocationStatus) -> Swift.Void

Comment: change type of closure param - currentLocation to (CLLocation?) i.e. Optional<CLLocation>. This should make complier happy.

Comment: Thanx @PuneetSharma